# How to do web scraping google-sheet for table within <div> by importxml or importhtml?

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape the data from table on the web page to googlesheet with the following code shown below.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://backoffice.onlineathome.ondemand.in.th/exams/search", "//div//div[contains(@class, 'rt-tr-group')]")
```

This shows the inspect element of the table on the web page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrs3h.jpg)

My code dose not work. What is the correct code?

Answer (score 1):

When I try to fetch that URL, the website is redirecting me to their login page:

[image]

This means that you are accessing it with your credentials (probably with a authentication cookie on your browser). However, google does not fetch with cookies, so you will not be able to access the data you are trying to access with `importhtml` nor `importxml`

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thank you very much.